# call valang validator in MultiActionController ModelAndView method... possible? how?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

is this possible?  i am basically making a Spring CRUD web app using MultiActionController class and would want my forms validated.  i have used a SimpleUrlController before and valang works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MultiActionControlller](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/multiaction/MultiActionController.html) API

> Consider direct usage of a ServletRequestDataBinder in your controller method, INSTEAD OF relying on a declared command argument. This allows for full control over the entire binder setup and usage, INCLUDING THE INVOCATION OF VALIDATORS  and the SUBSEQUENT EVALUATION of binding/validation errors.

So you can use

```
public class AddMultiActionController extends MultiActionController {

    public AddMultiActionController() {
        // Set up Valang according to your business requirement
        // You can use xml settings instead
        setValidators(new Validator [] {new CommandValidator(), new AnotherCommandValidator()});
    }

    public ModelAndView addCommand(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        Command command = new Command();

        // createBinder is a MultiActionController method
        ServletRequestDataBinder binder = createBinder(request, command);
        // Sets up any custom editor if necessary
        binder.registerCustomEditor(...);

        binder.bind(command);

        return (!(binder.getErrors().hasErrors())) ? new ModelAndView("success") : new ModelAndView("failure");
    }

    // similar approach as shown above
    public ModelAndView addAnotherCommand(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        AnotherCommand anotherCommand = new AnotherCommand();

        ...
    }
}
```

regards,